# How to catch an exception and use error codes when the requested PostgreSQL table can't be found?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, error-handling, npgsql

I am using Entity Framework so I believe I should catch an `NpgsqlException` since it's the .NET data provider for PostgreSQL. So let's say I make a query to the context. If the table doesn't exist in the PostgreSQL database, I want to catch the exception thrown and then manually create it. The code below is an example of how an entity is inserted, and I have attempted to use error handling to create the table if need be:

```
try
{
    return _context.Set(entityType).Add(entity);
}
catch (NpgsqlException)
{
    CreateEntityTable(entity); //a private method I made
    return _context.Set(entityType).Add(entity);
}
```

The problems are:

- I'm not 100% sure I should be catching an NpgsqlException
- I want to be sure that if an exception is thrown, it's because the table doesn't exist. I looked up [the PostgreSQL documentation of error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html) and error code 42P01 is undefined table. I believe I want to use that, but how? I looked up [the members of the NpgsqlException class](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlExceptionMembers.html), and I found ErrorCode. However, that's a type int. It would be nice if I could change the code above to be like the following

  ```
  try
  {
      return _context.Set(entityType).Add(entity);
  }
  catch (NpgsqlException ex)
  {
      if (ex.ErrorCode.Equals(42P01))
      {
          CreateEntityTable(entity); //a private method I made
          return _context.Set(entityType).Add(entity);
      }
  }
  ```

But I'm not sure if that makes sense (I'm not even sure how 42P01 can be an int).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the Code property of the NpgsqlException as that will contain PostgreSql error code.

Updating your example:

```
try
{
    return _context.Set(entityType).Add(entity);
}
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Code == "42P01")
    {
        CreateEntityTable(entity); //a private method I made
        return _context.Set(entityType).Add(entity);
    }
}
```

As an aside, I would suggest that you don't perform schema updates in your normal code. Only do something of this nature in an installer, or on start up as an upgrade.

Comment: Ah I missed the `Code` member -- I was looking at `ErrorCode` and `ErrorSql`, so I didn't see `Code`, thanks! Also I need to perform schema updates because in my context class I set the `Database.SetInitializer` to null so I manually have to create and alter tables. I won't get into the reason why, but it has to do with generating both entity classes and context classes dynamically with CodeDom -- it's pretty ugly.

Comment: Also I should note to anyone else who might find this useful and is also using Entity Framework that you can't catch the `NpgsqlException` directly. You first have to catch `EntityCommandExecutionException` and then use `ex.InnerException` to get `NpgsqlException`. I just tested this.

Comment: Just an update. Code is deprecated. Use SQLState instead.

Comment: Also worth noting that you should prefer the `PostgresErrorCodes` static class to raw strings when possible. This particular error code is called `PostgresErrorCodes.UndefinedTable`. I've submitted an edit to the answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

Tested and working with ASP NET Core 3.1 and ASP NET Core 5.0

```
try
{
    _context.Add(entity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    if (ex.GetBaseException() is PostgresException pgException)
    {
        switch (pgException.SqlState)
        {
            case "23505":
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This entity exists in the database");
                return View(yourViewModelFromRequest);
            default:
                throw;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
...
catch (NpgsqlException e)    
{
    switch (e.SqlState)
    {
         case "23505":
             MessageBox.Show("Some message...");
             break;
         default:
             MessageBox.Show("Some message. Details: " + e.Message);
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).